# Использование Delay в C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli

Может кто подскажет ,как правильно использовать метод Task.Delay в C++/CLI

Когда пишу Task.Delay(500) компилятор выдает ошибку

error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "."

Когда пишу Task:elay(500);

error C2039: Delay: не является членом "System::Threading::Tasks::Task"

Пробовал так Task->Delay(500) - опять ошибка.

А как правильно ?

Естественно ,у меня добавлено using namespace System::Threading::Tasks;

Библиотека msdn не содержит примера на с++,к сожалению

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806809/c-equivalent-of-nets-task-delay

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Это статический метод, обращение к нему записывается через два двоеточия.

```
System::Threading::Tasks::Task::Delay(500);
```

Или, если открыть пространство имён, то

```
using namespace System::Threading::Tasks;

Task::Delay(500);
```

---

Вся сила тасков проявляется с использованием асинхронности. В языке C# возможна запись `await Task.Delay(500);`. Но в C++/CLI это не реализовано. Поэтому, переходите на C#.

Comment: Прописал,как Вы посоветовали. Получил -  error C2039: Delay: не является членом "System::Threading::Tasks::Task"

Comment: @ValeryV - могу предположить, что используется FW4.0. Метод `Delay` доступен только с FW4.5.

Comment: Вы правы, у меня FWN 4.0 Если установлю FWN 4.5 должно пойти ?

Comment: @ValeryV - да..

Comment: И еще вопрос (простите за дилетантство ) - мне достаточно скачать и установить FWN 4.5 на комп или еще необходимо менять настройки VS 2010 ?

Comment: @ValeryV - Нужно будет поменять настройку проекта. Гм, как-то оно сложно [выглядит](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2921702/5045688). В проекте C# смена фреймворка делается в пару кликов мышки (ага, снова агитирую за переход на него).

Comment: @ValeryV - вот ещё [ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff770576.aspx). Вообще, это можно задать отдельным вопросом.

Comment: Если не трудно,то (начинающему !) как ? Если можно,алгоритм изменений

Comment: И еще вопросик - FWN 4.0 сносить или его присутствие не помешает ?

Comment: @ValeryV - не помешает. Все версии могут стоять на одном компе.

Comment: Увы,открыл ссылку Вашего сообщения - для моего VS2010 FWN4.5 не идет - надо начиная с VS2012

Comment: Установил VS 2015 и FWN 4.5. Все пошло ! Спасибо всем за советы

Comment: *"Запись в такой форме по эффекту ничем не отличается от вызова Thread::Sleep(500);"* - напротив, запись в такой форме принципиально отличается от `Thread::Sleep(500);` - она ничего не делает!

Comment: @PavelMayorov - кстати, да. Сейчас поправлю.

Answer (score 0):

Сверху добавьте:

```
using namespace System::Threading;
```

И пишите так:

```
Thread::Sleep(1000);
```

> Библиотека msdn не содержит примера на с++,к сожалению

Учитесь переводить синтаксис, а искать - не только в документации.

Comment: Меня Sleep не устраивает - нужно именно Delay